# EDIFACT (or) Baplie (or) Any EDI message structure in json format

Tags: json

I'm looking for a json structure for any EDIFACT message.

I tried in google but couldn't find anyone.

Could someone help me with a file or link?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JSON is simply a way to encode collections of values and dictionaries of values. It looks to me like an EDIFACT message is simply a collection of codes separated by new lines.  How you encode this depends on the consumer - if you have control over the consumer, then encode it however you like.

Comment: Your question is vague. Are you consuming the response from a known endpoint? Are you sending a EDIFACT package to a known endpoint? In either case, you need their documentation. Or, do you have data that you want to send to a new consumer via JSON (maybe a Webpage)? Do you have control over that consumer?  In that case, code it however you like.